# Do not split dates into separate lines

Tags: bug, design, dates

In some cases date when the answer has been closed is displayed on two lines:

> [image: closed]

> [image: закрыт]

According to [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/28476) at least the month name and date number should not be split into separate lines.

Could it please be fixed by using non-breakable spaces?